# exclude/include content files using IIS Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I have one MVC .Net Core project used for different clients.
So depending on the client I must replace some files. For example, logo images or css files, or even some cs files to implement custom functionalities.

To deploy to a server I customize csproj project configuration file to do this replace using items like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <_CustomFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/wwwroot/assests_clientX/images/**/*" />
  <DotNetPublishFiles Include="@(_CustomFiles)" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'ClientX-Debug' ">
    <DestinationRelativePath>wwwroot/assets/images/%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
  </DotNetPublishFiles>

  <!-- To not include original clientX files -->
  <Content Update="wwwroot\assests_clientX\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```

or

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="wwwroot\assets_clientX\ReadMe2.md" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'ClientX-Debug' ">
    <RelativePath>wwwroot\assets\ReadMe2.md</RelativePath>
  </ResolvedFileToPublish>

  <!-- To not include original clientX files -->
  <Content Update="wwwroot\assests_clientX\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This works well for deployment as it's applied at publishing phase.

But now, I want to have similar functionality when testing at Visual Studio using IIS Express.
For what I understand, IIS Express uses static files at wwwroot over my source code.
So my previous configuration is not applied and the replacement that I need to test a specific client is not used.

Is there a way to do this over IIS Express? Or to test my application with client specific files I have always to deploy over a server?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3 The mechanism does not give you much space to inject transformation steps. Did you try post build event?

Comment: I though about post build event but where to copy my client files? Because IIS Express seems to access my project files directly, it doesn't put wwwroot files at bin ou obj folders. I don't want to change my source files